# Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ be two independent random variables each with probability density function $fX_i(x_i) = 1$, for $0 < xi < 1$ for $i = 1, 2$.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Find:

(a) $E(X_1 X_2)$, and

(b) $Var(X_1 X_2)$.

Isn't (a) = zero, since this are independent?

How do I go about (b)

Comment: By symmetry $E(X_i)=\frac{1}{2}$. By independence $E(X_1X_2)=E(X_1)E(X_2)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(a) By symmetry $E(X_i)=\frac{1}{2}$. By independence $E(X_1X_2)=E(X_1)E(X_2)$.

(b) The variance of $X_1X_2$  is $E((X_1X_2)^2)-(E(X_1X_2))^2$.  It remains to calculate $E((X_1X_2)^2)$. By independence, this is $E(X_1^2)E(X_2^2)$.

To calculate $E(X_i^2)$, note this is $\int_0^1 x_i^2 \,dx_i$.

Comment: Don't I have to do the double integral for $E(X_1,X_2)$ or is it just  the integral of $E(x_i)$

Comment: I used independence to observe that $E(X_1X_2)=E(X_1)E(X_2)$. One could also say that the joint density of $(X_1,X_2)$ is $1$ on the square, and $0$ elsewhere, so $E(X_1X_2)=\int_0^1 \int_0^1 x_1x_2\,dx_1\,dx_2$. More work, same answer.

Comment: so your answer for (a) is just $1/2$?

Comment: No, it is $\frac{1}{4}$. The answer said that $E(X_i)=\frac{1}{2}$ and $E(X_1X_2)=E(X_1)E(X_2)$.